# bootstrap for rails do we need to keep all files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i downloaded bootstrap from their website. it is a zip file with the different css js img files. do we need to paste in both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css? isnt it the same file and i'm including them twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need to keep both the files since .min file is only a minified(compressed) version of bootstrap.css.In order to utilize all of bootstrap features you just need to include 2 files one css(either min or normal) and one js(either min or normal).You might also consider downloading it of cdn instead of keep a copy locally here is the link http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/